# How to integrate scss-lint to run on codeship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, codeship, scss-lint

I am working on a project for which we run rspec tests on codeship, along with rubocop for ruby style consistency.

We use [scss-lint](https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint) in development and as an editor integration for sass styles.

We would like to integrate scss-lint into codeship, so the we would get similar reports to what we get for rspec and rubocop after running our test suite.

Can anyone help with a detailed way to do this? Is there anything to achieve this in a quick and easy way? (similar to how rubocop is integrated).

I read something in the codeship documentation about docker, but we are not currently using docker, so I was wondering if there would be another solution.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply install scss-lint via RubyGems (or Bundler) and then just run it against your files.

Something like

```
gem install scss_lint
scss-lint app/assets/stylesheets/
```

To supply custom configuration options, simply include a `.scss-lint.yml` file in the same directory. See https://github.com/codeship/documentation/ for an example. (Even though that projects is run on our Docker platform, the basic steps for using it are the same.)